# Is async function a subset of function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

From what I know, `async function` expression returns an `AsyncFunction` object.

1. Does `AsyncFunction` inherit `Function`?
2. Is it okay to use async function in place of function? (e.g. as a callback parameter) If not, what could be a possible pitfall?

Comment: Could you please show an example of what you mean in #2?

Comment: If `foo` is an async function, `foo instanceof Function` returns `true`.

Comment: @Phil For example, when you start express server, you run `app.listen(port, callback)`. Can I safely pass in async function as callback here?

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in the comments. Also, why not try it and find out for yourself?

Comment: @Phil I know it does not produce any errors when I run it with async function. I have already tried it. That is why I asked if it is okay to use it. From my experience, things can go wrong without giving me error and I would like to know if there is anything I should be concered about when using async functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An async function is basically just a function that has been automatically converted to return a promise rather than an ordinary value. It can also use `await` internally as a shorthand for resolving the promise returned by another async function.

1. Yes. As shown below, it's type is `function`, and it's an instance of `Function`.

```js
async function afunc() {
  return 3;
}

console.log(typeof afunc);
console.log(afunc instanceof Function);
```

2. Yes, you can use it as a callback. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Examples) shows examples of using async functions with `setTimeout`.

```js
var resolveAfter2Seconds = function() {
  console.log("starting slow promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(20);
      console.log("slow promise is done");
    }, 2000);
  });
};

var resolveAfter1Second = function() {
  console.log("starting fast promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(10);
      console.log("fast promise is done");
    }, 1000);
  });
};

var sequentialStart = async function() {
  console.log('==SEQUENTIAL START==');
  const slow = await resolveAfter2Seconds(); // If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.
  const fast = await resolveAfter1Second();
  console.log(slow);
  console.log(fast);
}

var concurrentStart = async function() {
  console.log('==CONCURRENT START with await==');
  const slow = resolveAfter2Seconds(); // starts timer immediately
  const fast = resolveAfter1Second();

  console.log(await slow);
  console.log(await fast); // waits for slow to finish, even though fast is already done!
}

var stillSerial = function() {
  console.log('==CONCURRENT START with Promise.all==');
  Promise.all([resolveAfter2Seconds(), resolveAfter1Second()]).then(([slow, fast]) => {
    console.log(slow);
    console.log(fast);
  });
}

var parallel = function() {
  console.log('==PARALLEL with Promise.then==');
  resolveAfter2Seconds().then((message)=>console.log(message)); // in this case could be simply written as console.log(resolveAfter2Seconds());
  resolveAfter1Second().then((message)=>console.log(message));
}

sequentialStart(); // takes 2+1 seconds in total
// wait above to finish
setTimeout(concurrentStart, 4000); // takes 2 seconds in total
// wait again
setTimeout(stillSerial, 7000); // same as before
// wait again
setTimeout(parallel, 10000); // trully parallel
```

Answer (score 1):

According the the [ECMAScript 2017 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-function-objects)

> The AsyncFunction constructor is the %AsyncFunction% intrinsic object and is a subclass of **Function**.